# Moneris: 3-D Secure 2.0 Implementation

Tags: payment, 3d-secure

I have a website that redirects to a Moneris Hosted Pay Page in order to accept any payments. There is nothing Moneris or payment related on the website side, that is all done via the HPP.

My question is there anything that needs to be done in my case in order to upgrade to 3-D Secure 2.0 to get the added security benefits, or would this be done automatically on Moneris' side?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you refer as "Moneris Hosted Pay Page" is what Moneris calls "Moneris Checkout". In which case, they say in a blog post that this feature will automatically be upgraded to 3d secure 2.0.

https://community.moneris.com/blogs/b/announcements/posts/3-d-secure-2-0-what-you-need-to-know

> Moneris Checkout
> Our hosted payment solution that allows merchants to process online payments on their website now supports 3DS 2.0. From a development perspective all that is required is an integration to our Moneris Checkout (MCO) solution and quick configuration in the Merchant Resource Center (MRC). A sales order is required to enable 3DS on your merchant account. 3DS integrates into MCO by routing transaction requests to the card brands for a 3DS authentication request. Only transactions that are authenticated will be sent for authorization. If the issuing bank is not authenticating the transaction, the transaction is not eligible for fraud-related chargeback protection and sending for authorization would not be a good idea. Merchants who were using 3DS 1.0 via MCO will automatically have their transactions sent to 3DS 2.0. Please note that there are new fields in the Moneris Checkout response for 3DS 2.0, which you may choose to consume. Moneris will also control this transition from 3DS 1.0 to 3DS 2.0 within MCO.

Comment: That link no longer works.

Comment: @Liam indeed is it not working. Furthermore, it seems like they've removed all their blog posts. For the moment I can't find the article but may be it will reappear later on... By chance I pasted the portion of the text that contains the answer to the question that was being asked. Although I'm wondering if it's still valid information. I guess your best bet would be to write to their developer support.

Comment: I contacted Moneris support on Sep 14th. My enquiry has been forwarded to the team that manages the developer portal and community page.